# Restricting the number of connections per client key to OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

I have an OpenVPN setup and my clients authenticate with my server using the keys I've generated through pkitool.

The problem is that the clients can share the keys with others and effectively allow many others to connect through my VPN. How can I impose a restriction that a client key can only be used for one connection at a time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should check for the directive "duplicate-cn" in server.conf configuration file. Make sure it's NOT uncommented.

Comment: Thanks but I tried that and I can still login with the same key from two clients simultaneously.

Comment: Oh, got it. The wording was a little convoluted but it works. Thanks.